# Understanding RxSwift Observable Chain

Tags: swift, observable, reactive-programming, rx-swift

This is my a simplified version of my code:

```
var myObservable: Observable<MyEnum>

var modelObservable: Observable<Model?>

myObservable = myButton.rx.tap.asSignal()
 .asObservable()
 .flatMapLatest {
    getModel()
}.map { model in
    print("this is called")
    return model.prop == true ? MyEnum.first : MyEnum.second
}

 func getModel() -> Observable<Model?> {
     if let model = self.model.value {           
         return Observable.just(model)               
     }
     createModel()
     return modelObservable
 }
  myObservable.subscribe(onNext: { (enum) in
         switch enum {
         case .first:
             self.presentFirst()
         case .second:
             self.presentSecond()
         }
     }).disposed(by: bag)
```

I was expecting this code to mean that whenever myButton is tapped, this code would run and print "this is called", however, "this is called" is printed also when myOtherObservable is triggered, even when myButton is not tapped. Why does this happen? This makes me think I don't understand Rx. Also, how would I make it behave so that it only runs when the myButton is tapped?

Comment: What is `myOtherObservable`, and how is it related to `myButton` (i.e. why are you trying to `flatMapLatest` it in the first place?)

Comment: Give this a read first, and let me know if you still have questions https://medium.com/@navdeepsingh_2336/transforming-operators-map-flatmap-and-flatmaplatest-c233a536b38b

Comment: Hey @Alexander okay I updated it to be more in line with what I'm doing. When the button is tapped, I ultimately want to navigate somewhere, but not before getting the current model or fetching a new one.

Comment: I have no experience with Swift, but are you subscribing to `myObservable` anywhere? Somewhere you will need to subscribe to it to then perform the navigation.

Comment: This code doesn't print anything because there aren't any `subscribe`s in it. Post a minimal *runnable* example. And tell us how the actual output differed from what you expected.

Comment: @natecraft1 Did you read the article I linked?

Comment: @Alexander Yes I've read that article before. Is it possible that when I subscribe to the modelObservable from elsewhere that it triggers the chain, even though the button was not tapped?

Comment: @natecraft1 Then I'm afraid you didn't quite understand what you read. I'll try my best to explain it in my own words. Suppose you have  `let outterObservable: Observable<Observable<Foo>>` which is a stream wrapping some inner observables (let's call them `a`, `b`, `c`). When you `flatMap` over outterObservable, you create a new observable (call it `x`) of type `Observable<Foo>>`. When `a`, `b`, `c` emit new events (at any time in the future), `x` will emit them.

Comment: @natecraft1 As soon as `outterObservable` emits a new inner observable (`d`), `d` will be added to the list of "sources` whose events will be forwarded by `x`. An example of a `flatMap` would be if you had multiple monsters in a video game, whose weapons fire projectiles for which you need to check for collisions. `a`, `b`, `c` might be monsters, and `x` would be a stream that contains all projectiles fired by any monster. When a new monster `d` appears, his projectile events get emitted as part of `x` as well

Comment: @natecraft1 `flatMapLatest` is similar, but rather than concurrently forwarded all events from non-completed inner streams, it only forwards events from the *last* inner stream. So at first only `a`'s events are forwarded. As soon as `outterObservable` emits `b`, only `b`'s events are forwarded, and any new events from `a` are ignored. Likewise when `c` and `d` are emitted, they become the sole "sources" of events that `x` forwards, for the time interval during which they're the last thing emitted by `outterObservable `

Comment: In your case, every time you tap the button, `getModel()` is called, to provide a new observable. That observable's events are forwarded by the resulting observable (the one which you `map` over). Any new events that some down the `modelObservable` will go on to your `map`, until the next button tap. At that point, `getModel()` is called, a new observable is made, and it "takes over" the resulting observable. Now only its events get forwarded to `map`, and so on.

Comment: @natecraft1 your code would work if you guaranteed that `getModel` only emitted one event, and you used `flatMap`. That way, every button press causes exactly 1 model event to be emitted, even if a second button press is done before the first button press' event is done being emitted.

Comment: @Alexander Thanks for your explanation. I'm still having trouble wrapping my head around this:  "Any new events that some down the modelObservable will go on to your map, until the next button tap." It seems to make sense in the article, but not in the context of what I'm doing. Basically, it seems like what I'm trying to do is not a great use of Rx, or this implementation is just way off. All I want is to listen to a tap event, grab a model if there is one, or fetch to create one if there isn't, then navigate   to another controller. If possible can you show me how you would do that?

Comment: @natecraft1 What I just said should apply `your code would work if you guaranteed that getModel only emitted one event, and you used flatMap. That way, every button press causes exactly 1 model event to be emitted, even if a second button press is done before the first button press' event is done being emitted.`

Comment: @natecraft1 I can't show you an example, because you haven't provided a minimal viable example.

Comment: @Alexander is there any way I can update the code so you can provide an example? I'm curious how to ensure that getModel only emits one event. Do you just do that with a .take(1)?

Comment: @natecraft1 `is there any way I can update the code so you can provide an example?` -> Provide a link to a minimal compiling and working project that I can easily tinker with. "Do you just do that with a .take(1)?" -> I think that could work, but it's probably just better to change the implementation of `getModel`

Comment: @Alexander well the example project would be extremely hard to reproduce the specific navigation bug I have. I agree getModel implementation is probably wrong, how would you modify it? Basically I'm thinking of it more in terms of promises, where I can just return a value if it already exists or create a new promise for an api call, but I realize the fact that I'm returning separate observables messes with the observable chain. I don't know a clean way to do this in a reactive way

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186329/discussion-between-alexander-and-natecraft1).

Comment: Years later, this makes sense. Thanks @Alexander

Comment: Heh, glad to hear it.